# How should a good cross-validated model look like?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, convergence

I am baffled if i should make my model converge at every fold or let it converge at the last fold. Can someone explain me what path should i choose (for a regressional model)? My current "best" looks like (loss and MSE are multiplied by 100, K-fold is used):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Score per fold
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 1 - Loss: 12.802508473396301 - MSE: 5.588992312550545
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 2 - Loss: 11.519307643175125 - MSE: 4.953135922551155
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 3 - Loss: 11.073733866214752 - MSE: 4.5293498784303665
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 4 - Loss: 11.06119304895401 - MSE: 4.478055983781815
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 5 - Loss: 10.377947241067886 - MSE: 3.779773786664009
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average scores for all folds:
> MSE: 4.665861576795578 (+- 0.5956097483088829)
> Loss: 11.366938054561615
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you please explain the sense in which you refer to "converge" in this question?  How one does cross-validation ought to be (and is) unrelated to the numerical details of how one fits a model, leaving us with no evident meaning of "converge."

Comment: I am afraid my model does not learn everything from each fold and hence i might be able to get a better one if i do it so that i have for example: 3.,7 3.5, 3.3, 3.9, 3.4 MSE... My question is what would be better for a regressional model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the performance to be good on average, between the folds. It is expected to see some variability in the results. On another hand, it is bad if you see big discrepancies. Even if your model would perform very well on all but one folds, where it would perform poorly, this would mean that it can overfit to unlucky data configurations, so you have no guarantee about its out-of-sample performance.

Comment: Great answer. I do understand this.